# Activity On Destroy always called in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on one application in which i am using broadcast receiver. I am using activity's on destroy method to unregister the receiver. When i move from one activity to another,its onDestry always called. Please tell  me why it happened. As per my knowledge activity goes to the pause state when we move from one activity to another. Please help.

Comment: Are you calling finish() while moving to another activity ?

Comment: There's also a developer setting which will cause Activities to be destroyed as soon as they're stopped - see 'Immediately destroy activities' on the page http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html.  You might want to check that it's not enabled on your device.

Comment: Incidentally, the setting is there so developers can test this behaviour reliably, and that's useful because the system can choose to destroy stopped activities whenever it wants.  So the activity's destruction probably isn't the right point at which to unregister your broadcast receiver.

Comment: check in developers options whether Do not keep activities option is on or not

Answer (score 0):

`onDestroy()` can well be called any time after your activity becomes fully invisible.

You should unregister your receiver in `onPause` and register it on `onResume`. Or, in `onStart` and `onStop`